# Circle linear gradient with photoshop?

Tags: photoshop-effects

I have to do a circle like this: [image]

But i've a problem.. in photoshop there is this effect: [image]

BUT IT'S DIFFERENT! I need an effect to combine colors, not separated colors.

Is this possible? Thanks

Comment: Make the gradient linear

Comment: @AndrewH why not make this an answer?

Answer (score 1):

As the others stated - make a ring and fill it with a linear gradient.

- Create an ellipse with the Ellipse Tool (<kbd>U</kbd>)

[image]

- Using the Path Selection Tool (<kbd>A</kbd>), click on your ellipse and copy it
- Use Past in Place (<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) to place the copied circle onto your initial one and then use Free Transform (<kbd>CMD</kbd>+T) to shrink the copied circle down.  **Make sure to hold <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd> while you do!**
- With your new, smaller ellipse still selected, click on Subtract From Shape in the Properties Panel (Window > Properties)

[image]

- Apply a linear gradient to your new ring

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This image was created with a different technique. Notice that the **gradient is linear** and the **circle has sharp edges**.

Off the top, the easiest way I can think of to recreate this is to create a vector circle and fill it with a linear gradient.